# 12.10, ATI drivers help?

Tags: 12.10, drivers, ati, fglrx

I just downloaded Ubuntu today and I love it! I'm trying to install the ATI drivers by the guide posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200), but I get an error after I choose to generate the drivers for the distro, and I get the following in the log file:

```
Package build failed!
Package build utility output:
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 294: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: debclean: not found
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 295: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: dpkg-buildpackage: not found
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 294: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: debclean: not found
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 295: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: dpkg-buildpackage: not found
[Error] Generate Package - error generating package : Ubuntu/quantal
```

Can someone provide some help here? I'd like to get this working right soon.

Comment: Perhaps ATI radeon guys don't support Your card for use with 3.5+ kernels. You can search that on Your own, or post the card info here.

Comment: why don't you install it from software sources--> "additional drivers" tab ?